# How to move Xcode split panes around

Tags: xcode

Normally I can open two Editor panes in Xcode: one for the `.h` and one for the `.m` as counterpart. But presently I need to open four panes. So I click on the upper-right + sign. But this cause the splits to happen on the right pane so that I have one left pane and three right panes stacked vertically. How might I move the panes around so that one pane shows in each quadrant? This very easy to do in eclipse. I imagine Xcode can do it too.

Here is what I want

```
_______________________
|          |          |
|   .h     |   .m     |
|__________|__________|
|          |          |
|   .h     |   .m     |
|__________|__________|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You imagine wrong. Xcode can't do that. (The problem is partly that Xcode has no notion of equivalent panes. You always have one "real" editor and everything else is an "assistant" to it.)

Your best bet is to use separate tabs (or windows). These can be configured differently, though in your case I think you just want two tabs configured the same way (assistant on right).

Comment: I cannot find the separate tabs option. Do you know how to get them?

Comment: New > Tab (there are other ways but that will get you started).